# How to Active Tab which form is submit using bootstrap tabs by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs staffTabs">
        <li class="active " id="tabOne"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-first" @*onclick="edit(1)"*@>Reminder</a></li>
        <li class="" id="TabsTwo"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-second" @*onclick="edit(2)"*@>Confirmation</a></li>
        <li class="" id="TabsThree"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-third" @*onclick="edit(3)"*@>ReSchedule</a></li>
        <li class="" id="TabsFour"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-four" @*onclick="edit(4)"*@>Canceling</a></li>
        <li class="" id="TabsFive"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-fifth" @*onclick="edit(5)"*@>Thank You</a></li>
    </ul>
```

these are the 5 tabs .Each tabs has its own unique ID.Each form has its own action method in controller.The problem is,i want to active that tab which data is submit using JavaScript.Because i am sending id to get method which tab data is submit and then store that value in view beg and put that value in hidden field and accesses that id in JavaScript function by GetElementByID now how i active that tab which the id i have in  JavaScript function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code may be suite with your requirement.

In submit action you set

```
ViewBag.ActiveTab = 2;
```

And update UI to check active tab to generate class active

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs staffTabs">
    <li class="@(ViewBag.ActiveTab == 1 ? "active" : string.Empty)" id="tabOne"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-first" onclick="edit(1)">Reminder</a></li>
    <li class="@(ViewBag.ActiveTab == 2 ? "active" : string.Empty)" id="TabsTwo"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-second" onclick="edit(2)">Confirmation</a></li>
    <li class="@(ViewBag.ActiveTab == 3 ? "active" : string.Empty)" id="TabsThree"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-third" @*onclick="edit(3)"*@>ReSchedule</a></li>
    <li class="@(ViewBag.ActiveTab == 4 ? "active" : string.Empty)" id="TabsFour"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-four" @*onclick="edit(4)"*@>Canceling</a></li>
    <li class="@(ViewBag.ActiveTab == 5 ? "active" : string.Empty)" id="TabsFive"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-fifth" @*onclick="edit(5)"*@>Thank You</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
$(".nav.staffTabs>li").click(function(){
    $(".nav.staffTabs>li").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs staffTabs">
        <li class="active " id="tabOne"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-first" @*onclick="edit(1)"*@>Reminder</a></li>
        <li class="" id="TabsTwo"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-second" @*onclick="edit(2)"*@>Confirmation</a></li>
        <li class="" id="TabsThree"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-third" @*onclick="edit(3)"*@>ReSchedule</a></li>
        <li class="" id="TabsFour"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-four" @*onclick="edit(4)"*@>Canceling</a></li>
        <li class="" id="TabsFive"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-fifth" @*onclick="edit(5)"*@>Thank You</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: On click is commented.
After the submission of form i send id by hard code like 0 for tab1,1 for tab2 to get method and store that id in view beg and store View beg value in a hidden filed and then i write a JavaScript function and access the hidden field value in JavaScript function have the id but now i have to active the tab which ID i have

Comment: I see, and check your answer as well using viewbag we can. Thank you

Comment: actually I thought this because he is also doing `href="#<tabl-number>"` everything here via hash